# Query from ledger in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am able to save my data in CouchDB.As per my understanding, the ledger(stored inside blocks) contains the history of changes.

Is there any way to query that ledger?

How will I know which block I need to query (There are 100s of blocks and the data is in particular ledger in the block) Basically, I just want to see a history of particular data from the block and I do not know the block number.

Is it possible?

Any help/suggestion/comment would be appreciated.

Comment: Which SDK are you using to initiate a transaction on the ledger? There are api's available to query the ledger with or without block id

Comment: @Faran I am using node.js sdk

Answer (score 0):

Using the Node.js SDK you can query the ledger in multiple ways:

1. Query via chaincode: In this you write your code in the chaincode to query the ledger and call this using the Node.js SDK. This is when you don't have the TX ID or the Block ID.

Follow the query method in this example to write the query chaincode: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.1/balance-transfer/artifacts/src/github.com/example_cc/node/example_cc.js

2. Query Couch DB directly: In this you write the SDK code to query the ledger directly without going through the chaincode. This is when you know the TX ID or the Block ID.

Follow this example to write the SDK for the queries: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.1/balance-transfer/app/query.js

Answer (score 0):

You can install composer-rest-server. It will start loopback server and exposes rest APIs for all the assets and historian. You can query historian to get all the transactions.